# NUnit test fails when not using lambda expression for assertion

Tags: c#, testing, lambda, nunit, assert

If came across a weird problem while writing some `NUnit` tests. The tests were more complex, but I broke it down to the following code.

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    // Assert.That(test(), Is.True.After(1000, 100)); // Fail
    Assert.That(() => test(), Is.True.After(1000, 100)); // Success
}

static int count = 0;

bool test()
{
    Console.WriteLine(++count);
    if (count == 2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Why does the test only succeed when I use the lambda expression?

**EDIT:**

To make it more clear: 
In the first line it seems that `test()` only gets executed once while `() => test()` gets executed multiple times.

Comment: The first one is passing a `bool` and the second a `Action<bool>`.

Comment: @juharr Well observed, but that's not an explanation.

Comment: @juharr I guess that's correct. I would've expected at least a compiler warning if you don't use a delegate.

Comment: OK I see what you mean now about it being run multiple times.  I think that's because of the polling of the `Is.True.After`.  Try it without the polling and it should only call the action once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you are using the `Is.True.After` that includes polling.  By passing in a `Action<bool>` it has to call that action to test if it is `true`.  That will result in multiple calls and your `count` will go up and eventually it will return `true`.  If you remove the polling argument it should only run the action after the desired time.